# nested loops in a program not sure what is being printed

Tags: loops, for-loop

What will be printed?

Given:

for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {

for (int j = 0; j < 4; j += 2) {

```
System.out.println("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
```

}

}

Comment: You can try it out yourself, see what is being printed

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can easily do yourself through a compiler or even by counting on your fingers. Here is your output:

```
i = 2, j = 0
i = 2, j = 2
i = 3, j = 0
i = 3, j = 2
```

If you need to compile anything and you dont have a Java IDE to do so, you can do it online with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php